# Change data by download as pdf in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

i have a highchart and want to be able to download as pdf. But before downloading, to the highchart a title should be added as html. Is this possible? Like event:beforePrint and afterPrint, but just for downloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom click event for the 'Download PDF document' button:

```
exporting: {
    menuItemDefinitions: {
        // Custom definition
        downloadPDF: {
            onclick: function() {
                this.update({
                    title: {
                        text: 'New title'
                    }
                }, false);

                this.exportChart({
                    type: 'application/pdf'
                });

                this.update({
                    title: {
                        text: 'Old title'
                    }
                }, false);
            },
            text: 'Download PDF document'
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/02aw13ht/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.menuItemDefinitions

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update